# Дополнительное окно при нажатий на кнопку (Python)

Tags: python, tkinter, button

При нажатий на кнопку вместе с предусмотренным окном открывается дополнительное (не предусмотренное) окно

Выглядит это так
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Код программы

```
import webbrowser
import sys
from tkinter import *

def Start():
    print("Начало")
    webbrowser.open("https://www.youtube.com/", new=0)

def Browser():
    root = Tk()
    root.title("Assistant")
    root.geometry("550x500")
    Toplevel(root)
    
    button = Button(
    root, 
    background="#555",     
    foreground="#ccc",    
    padx="20",             
    pady="8",
    font="16",
    text="Начало", 
    command=Start)
    button.pack()
    
    root.mainloop()  


root = Tk()
root.title("Assistant")
root.geometry("550x500")

btn = Button(text="Браузер",         
             background="#555",     
             foreground="#ccc",    
             padx="20",             
             pady="8",
             font="16",            
             command = Browser              
             )
btn.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вы сами его создаёте командой `Toplevel(root)`.

- Первое окно создаётся командой `root = Tk()` в коде верхнего уровня.
- Второе окно вместе со вторым экземпляром *tkinter* создаётся командой `root = Tk()` в обработчике кнопки.
- Третье окно, привязанное ко второму экземпляру *tkinter*, создаётся командой `Toplevel(root)`.

Так что программа работает в соответствии с написанным кодом.

Comment: Спасибо за помощь 
Впредь буду более бдительным